# Parsing in PHP using curl

Tags: php, parsing, curl

I'm creating parser for data extract from www.lolking.net. 
I need personal lolking score (Personal Ratings->5vs5 Solo).
I can extract that, when i have account link (e.g.lolking.net/summoner/na/407750)
I know i can give url in the form of "lolking.net/search?name=user_name&region=region_name" (GET form). When i'm entering url in that form in the web browser, it works, but when i replaced account url to that form i saw error.
I would like to give username through variable (lolking.net/search?name=$user&region=NA), but i don't know how. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.lolking.net/summoner/na/407750');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$query=trim(strip_tags($query));
curl_close($curl_handle);
preg_match('/Solo 5v5\s+.+\s+.+\s+\d{3,4}/',$query,$sub);
preg_match('/Points\s+\d{3,4}/',$sub[0], $result);
preg_match('/\d+/',$result[0], $value);
$score = $value[0];
echo $score;
?>
```

Comment: what error do you see?

Comment: no results, even when match_pattern is disabled

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying to grab your information from LoL King i would recommend using the official LoL API [see here](http://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/593/1863)

Comment: heh, simplicity is ultimate sophistication. Thank You

Comment: LOL API doesn't offer Personal Score(ELO) preview :(

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to create cookie to hold you session. use this one.

```
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie2);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie2);
```